# tmux: small rendered view when opening buffers

Tags: tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running WSL-2 on windows with Ubuntu.  I am running `wsl` from Powershell.  After some update or another, any `tmux` session I open in the powershell renders with a very tiny screen size.

`tmux a -dt` does not change the screen size to fit the bounds.  Additionally, there are none of the white dots one usually sees with this problem, so it seems as if something is a bit wonky.

Only trying to diagnose this issue and discover possible solutions to try out -- I assume it is some setting on the windows side.

My Windows tmux config is:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
set -g status-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# vim copy, C-p paste
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

And this has not changed for months.

So, to summarize:

1. I have made no changes in my tmux setup for months
2. Tmux *was* working, now it is not
3. The issue I am experiencing is a tiny rendered area when opening a buffer
4. `tmux a -dt` does not solve the issue
5. white dots do not appear to fill in the empty space around the small view area

And my question amounts to: what could possibly be going wrong, and has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but likely the terminal used by your Powershell window is not suitable for Unix programs.  Can you try opening Powershell in a Microsoft Terminal window instead and seeing if that works?

Comment: @bk2204 I'll try that instead